# Oracle query data where column value with comma to check the value contains or not

Tags: oracle

I would like to query data to check at least contains 1 IP Address.

Example I have data below:

```
PROFILEID   PROFILE_NAME        ACTIVE  DATEADDED               ADDEDBY LOCATIONID_FK   ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS
PF0001      Normal Working Day  Y       9/30/2017 5:53:39 PM    US0001  LC0001          192.168.183.205, 192.168.183.28
PF0004      Ramadhan            N       10/12/2017 10:38:02 AM  US0001  LC0003  
PF0002      Ramadhan            N       9/30/2017 5:55:50 PM    US0001  LC0001          192.168.183.205, 192.168.183.28
PF0003      Normal Working Day  Y       10/3/2017 5:23:05 PM    US0001  LC0003          192.168.184.20, 192.168.184.15
```

As you can see column `ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS` has more ip with comma.

And now I want to check with query where `ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN ('192.168.183.28')`, but got no result.

```
SELECT PROFILEID FROM WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE P WHERE P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS IN ('192.168.183.28');
```

How to do the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for a sub-string surrounded by the delimiters:

```
SELECT PROFILEID
FROM   WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE P
WHERE  ', ' || P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS || ', ' LIKE '%, 192.168.183.28, %';
```

However, a better way would be to change your database table so that you are not storing multiple items in one value:

```
CREATE TABLE Allowed_IP_Addresses(
  PROFILEID          VARCHAR2(20)
                     CONSTRAINT AllowIP__ProfileID__FK REFERENCES WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE( PROFILEID ),
  CLASSA             NUMBER(3,0),
  CLASSB             NUMBER(3,0),
  CLASSC             NUMBER(3,0),
  CLASSD             NUMBER(3,0),
  IP_ADDRESS         VARCHAR2(15)
                     GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CLASSA||'.'||CLASSB||'.'||CLASSC||'.'||CLASSD) VIRTUAL,
  CONSTRAINT AllowIP__P_A_B_C_D__PK PRIMARY KEY ( PROFILEID, CLASSA, CLASSB, CLASSC, CLASSD )
);
```

Then you can store the values individually (and easily search for sub-net ranges) and join it to the profile table as needed.

Comment: @apomene `WHERE  ', ' || P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS || ', ' LIKE` that is why the column has the delimiters added before and after, so that it will still be matched in just that case.

Comment: @HiDayurie Dave: please note that the solution with like will not allow you to compare multiple IP addresses. You would have to split IP addresses from the string in the table which would complicate things quite a bit. So please follow the advice given by MT0 to normalize data - this will help you write easier code to maintain, and will provide better performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for exact matches you can use `like` condition or `instr` function, but you will need to concatenate commas on both sides, as in:

```
select profileid
  from wa_bt_tbl_profile p
 where ', ' || p.allowed_ip_address || ',' like '%, 192.168.183.28,%'
```

[Edit]
If you do not use commas when comparing IP addresses you may get unwanted results - for instance, if you used address 10.10.10.10 for comparison, without commas valid results would also be 110.10.10.10, 10.10.10.101, 110.10.10.101, etc.

I suggest you remove space between comma and IP address - it just makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: Yes, what is the problem with that? Query will return it. This is why I added commas around p.allowed_ip_address.

Answer (score -1):

use `like` instead:

```
SELECT PROFILEID FROM WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE P WHERE P.ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS LIKE '%192.168.183.28%'
```

The above is a 'dirty fix' on a bad table use. You should avoid storing concatenated strings on the same entry. 
Also take into account that the above query will be valid for a subset of given IPs. Above IP will guarantee you have a correct result, however using an IP like e.g. 192.168.183.2, would might bring unwanted entries, like e,g 192.16.183.21,...

Comment: `LIKE '%19.168.183.25%'` will match `19.168.183.25` as well as `219.168.183.25`, `19.168.183.256` and `119.168.183.250` (among many others).

Comment: @MT0  I wrote like 192.168.183.28 not  19.168.183.25, that means tha 280 0r 28x is not an option....Also 19.168.183.256 is not a valid IP, please review sth before you post

Comment: Problem with the query is that it will match ANY IP address that ends with 28, which may be anything from 280 to 289 (and obviously 28 itself).

Comment: @GoranStefanović. Gyus please think...before you post, 28x can not be a valid ending IP. IP goes up to 255. 280 or 281 or 289, or .... is not a valid IP

Comment: @apomene: you are right about the ranges, but who is to say that OP will not compare addresses with, say, 10.1.1.5 tommorow?

Comment: @GoranStefanović  The crucial problem lies on table bad design and use. Storing concatenated strings in the same filed is bad table use.  For this bad use OP want a fix. The answer I am offering is a dirty fix on this, of course it is not optimal.

Comment: MT0's example is based on the assumption that OP will not always compare to that one address, but requirement will change over time. We should provide reusable queries, not just queries that will work for one specific case.

Comment: @apomene Why do you think I changed the IP address from `192.168.183.28` to `19.168.183.25`? Maybe it was so i could highlight exactly where the problem with your solution was and that it would be too permissive in its matches while still being a valid (if alternate) IP address.