# Split '|' seperated values field and join with another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have one table named htask with column name htaskName
The values of htask may contain '|' seperate values like 12|55|27

I would like to split all of them and join each value with another table call stask
stask includes two column htaskName and staskName.

I've already try rtrim but not succeeded

Database version: Oracle 9i

Comment: Please include sample data for the two tables as well as the output.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM htask h INNER JOIN stask s ON ( '|' || h.htaskname || '|' LIKE '%|' || s.hTaskName || '|%' )` may be a lot easier than splitting the delimited column into rows and joining .... still would be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46706561/1509264) and probably several others

Comment: Thank you for your supporting. It works perfectly.